# Is there any way to flag a User?

Tags: support, moderation, flagging, users

Just a few minutes ago, I observed a new user account post an answer to a question.  This answer was essentially unhelpful because it didn't really work.  At the end of the short answer was a link to a Salesforce-related blog post that had nothing to do with the question or answer at hand.

"On a hunch" I clicked into the user's profile and saw three answers all given recently.  As suspected, when I drilled into those answers (one which was unhelpful, and one which, actually, seemed to be helpful) the same blog post link was in each answer.  I proceeded to flag each of these answers as *Spam*, and someone has already taken care of those answers. *(Thank you!)*

All that is not to "toot my own horn", but rather to lead into the actual question:

**Is there a way to flag a *user* ?**

I'm asking because if something similar happens with way more than three answers to flag, it would be much quicker, simpler and (I would assume) "cleaner" for the moderators/admin to deal with one flag rather than a number of flags.

*I searched Meta and Help Center and did not see anything directly related to this.  My apologies if I missed something obvious.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not as such. What you can do is use the custom flag "in need of moderator intervention" on a post by the user. You'll be able there to include a specific note, which can direct us to look at the user rather than solely at the flagged post. In that case, you don't necessarily need to go to the effort of flagging all of their posts - your message can direct us where to look.

Thanks for identifying that spam. It was surprisingly well camouflaged in what looked like a genuine attempt to answer, but with a totally irrelevant blog link embedded. I've removed all of the offending posts and the user from the site.

Comment: Thank _you_ for getting rid of those - and so quickly.  Would the ability to flag a user be something that A) would be feasible to implement, and B) be at all helpful to moderators, to warrant adding it as a feature request?

Comment: It's not something that would make a ton of difference for me personally, but my experience may not be universal!